# How To make two modules depend on eache other

Tags: java, android

I have 2 modules in my project (module A, module B) am able to access classes from Module B in Module A But I can't access classes from module A in my Module B.

(Sorry for my English I am French)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't; that will lead to a circular dependency, which isn't allowed.

Take the parts that rely on both modules, and put them into a new module, then import A and B into it.

Comment: You save me. Thank you